# Django-registration redirect on registration

Tags: django, django-registration

I'm trying to redirect the user after registration with django registration. Currently it still redirects to the main page '/'. I attempted to extend the RegistrationView but it still is not working. Here is my current code:

views.py

```
from registration.views import RegistrationView 
class RegView(RegistrationView):
    def get_success_url(self, user):
        success_url =  '/trips/' 
        return success_url
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
```

Any help on how I can extend the view and redirect to the right page would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried using `{'next_page': '/go/here/'}` in your url like `url(r'^accounts/register/$', RegView.as_view(), name='registration_register',{'next_page': '/go/here/'} )`

Answer (score 0):

You should subclass `registration.backends.simple.views.RegistrationView`:

```
from registration.backends.simple.views import RegistrationView
```

[Docs](http://django-registration.readthedocs.io/en/2.1.1/simple-workflow.html#configuration).